# Unable to install Python3 via Homebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I want to install python 3 via Homebrew.  Here is the error I get:

```
Error: You must `brew link xz gdbm' before python3 can be installed
```

Now when I do 'brew link xz gdbm' I get this:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.11... Error: Could not symlink include/gdbm.h/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

I tried the following options to fix this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/include
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
   chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

After this I tried to install python3 again but I am getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just install Python 3 the normal way... From Python.org?

Comment: `brew doctor` may suggest solutions if you encounter problems like this in the future. Ian's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `/usr/local/include is not writable.`
>
> `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/include`

The directory you want to chown is /usr/local/include, or /usr/local proper.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. Run

```
brew doctor
```

(probably you also need to update brew if it's old with command brew update)
and after warnings are cleared python installation should move forward without a hitch.

Please note you can run brew doctor as many times until all warnings are gone.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
    brew doctor
```

then you'll see a diagnosis like this:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run brew link on these:

  makedepend
```

it means you can fix by running this code:

```
 brew link makedepand
```

so now this works.

```
 brew install pyenv
```